Issue with Copy Functionality in WebView Using Mac Catalyst
I am developing a Mac app via Mac Catalyst and encountering an issue with WebView. Specifically, I'm loading a webpage (e.g., https://translate.google.com) in WKWebView, but when I press the copy button on the page, the text doesn't actually copy to the clipboard.
This issue occurs on certain websites, yet the copy functionality is still accessible on others.
I've attempted modifying the UserAgent without any success. Here is the relevant part of my code:
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.preferences = WKPreferences()
    config.defaultWebpagePreferences.preferredContentMode = .desktop
    
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(webView)
    webView.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    webView.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    //webView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.5 Safari/605.1.15"

    webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    if let url = URL(string: "https://translate.google.com") {
        let req = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(req)
    }
}

How to use AppKit WKWebView in a Mac Catalyst App?
https://github.com/codemirror/dev/issues/977
